# LINQ Select Statement making many SQL Calls

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to run a Select on an IQUeryable linked to a database query. Its working correctly, but for all the properties being selecte-d, its running a seperate query.

My code looks something like this

```
IQueryable<MyDataSource> data = [Some Complicated Query I've been Building Up];

var results = data.Select(d => new 
{
A = d.A,
B = d.B,
C = d.C

}).Take(100).ToArray();
```

Now, this is taking ages, even though the actual Query isn't taking that long.
When I ran an SQL profiler on it, I'm finding out that its running a different SQL select procedure for each property I'm selecting - for each entity I'm returning (so in the above example around 300 different queries, as well as the actual first query to perform the filtering).

I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong here, what is it? I'm expecting it to run a single large query - which selects the right columns from the datasource (You know Select top 100 d.A, d.B, d.C from [bla bla] ), not all this mess.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051287/using-linq-select-to-cast-into-new-type-is-too-slow?rq=1

Comment: You need to use `IQueryable<MyDataSource>` instead of `IEnumerable<MyDataSource>`.

Comment: Are those values marked as lazy, perhaps? Also: I would be very interested in seeing how `[Some Complicated Query I've been Building Up]` is *composed* - in particular, at what point it becomes `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>`. It is vitally important that `data` is `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, if you want to make the `select` include exactly the 3 properties cited.

Comment: Ok sorry. Its IQueryable<MyDataSource> got confused. Fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the lazy/eager loading using DataLoadOptions

This will force eager loading for B

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<a>(a => a.B);
dc.LoadOptions = options;
```